# How to get a float value from a Input.GetKey in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got it to work but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. Basically its to orbit around the player and you use Q and E to change the value of angle so that you can orbit left and right.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) {
        gotQ = orbitSpeed;
    }

    else {
        gotQ = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
        gotE = orbitSpeed;
    }
    else {
        gotE = 0;
    }
    angle = angle + gotQ - gotE;
```

As you can see I set gotQ and gotE to a positive float value when a key is pressed and set it to 0 when its not. Then angle is changed accordingly. Im trying to clean this up and make it use less resources.

Comment: Hm...so have you identified any specific performance problems with this approach that you're trying to address?

Comment: We don't see that you set those two variables to float values because none of your variable declarations and definitions are included in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.Q ) )
    angle += orbitSpeed;
if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.E ) )
    angle -= orbitSpeed;
```

That having been said, the "resources" that are "used" by your piece of code are negligible, and the resources used by this piece of code are negligibly smaller, if not exactly the same.  But readability always counts, and this is certainly more readable.